# $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos \left(x\right)}-\sqrt[3]{\cos \left(x\right)}}{\sin ^2\left(x\right)}\right)$ without L'Hospitals rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos \left(x\right)}-\sqrt[3]{\cos \left(x\right)}}{\sin ^2\left(x\right)}\right)=?$$

How to solve it without using L'Hospitals rule?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Make the substitution $u = 1- \sqrt[6]{\cos x}$.

Answer (score 9):

With  $u=\sqrt[6]{\cos x}\to 1$ the term equals $$\frac{u^3-u^2}{1-u^{12}}=u^2\cdot \frac{u-1}{1-u^{12}}=-u^2\frac1{1+u+u^2+\ldots +u^{11}}\to -\frac1{12}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use *equivalents* and *Taylor's formula* at order $2$: we know that

- $\cos x=1-\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$,
- $\sqrt{1+u}=1+\dfrac u2+o(u)$,
- $\sqrt[3]{1+u}=1+\dfrac u3+o(u)$
  Thus the numerator gives, by composition:
  $$\sqrt[2]{\cos x}-\sqrt[3]{\cos x}=\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}4\Bigr)-\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}6\Bigr)+o(x^2)=-\frac{x^2}{12}+o(x^2)$$
  so that $\;\sqrt[2]{\cos x}-\sqrt[3]{\cos x}\sim_0 -\dfrac{x^2}{12}$, and
  $$\frac{\sqrt[2]{\cos x}-\sqrt[3]{\cos x}}{\sin^2 x}\sim_0 -\dfrac{x^2}{12 x^2}=-\frac1{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Also
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+(\cos x-1)}-1}{\cos x-1}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+(\cos x-1)}-1}{\cos x-1}\right)\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}{\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2}=\frac{-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})\frac{1}{2}}{1^2}=-\frac{1}{12}
$$